# I would like to beable to stack rows of one matrix in a special way

Tags: matlab

If I have a matrix whose rows are r1,r2,r3. Each row has length 4. So the matrix is 3x4. I would like to generate a 4x8 matrix of the form

```
[    r1    0 0 0 0]
[    r2    0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0     r2   ]
[0 0 0 0     r3   ]
```

I can not see how to do this using `repmat` or `reshape`.

If am interested in applying this to a mxn matrix. So in the general case I would like diagonal blocks of 2 rows of length n.

Comment: how about using `kron`?

Comment: In your more general case, how many rows should be repeated? eg if you had 7 rows, should the result have blocks with rows 1-2,2-3,3-4,4-5,5-6,6-7 or just 1-2,3-4,4-5,6-7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So suppose you have the following matrix

```
m=4;n=3;
A = rand(m,n);
```

I don't see any problem using a for loop here

```
B = [];
for i = 1:m-1
    B = blkdiag(B, A(i:i+1,:));
end
```

but if you are feeling fancy for generalizations and like matlab (which is rare)

```
zzz = [[1:m-1]',[2:m]'];
B = arrayfun(@(x) A(zzz(x,:)',:),[1:m-1],'UniformOutput',false);
C = blkdiag(B{[1:m-1]});
```

---

If there was a list comprehension and argument unpacking in matlab like python it would have been this easy

```
B = scipy.linalg.block_diag(*[A[x:x+2,:] for x in range(m-1)])
```

Comment: The blkdiag command seems to work nicely when generalizing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that use of repmat and reshape in your case is not needed. Maybe something of that sort would do the job?

```
r      = rand(3,4);
M      = zeros(4,8);

M(1,1:4)    = r(1,:);
M(2,1:4)    = r(2,:);
M(3,5:8)    = r(2,:);
M(4,5:8)    = r(3,:);
```

If you want to extend it to more general case you could go in this direction:

```
n = 12;
m = 8;

nrows_r = m/2 + 1; % make sure m is actually divisible by 2
ncols_r = n / (m/2);

r      = rand(nrows_r, ncols_r);
M2     = zeros(m,n);

for i = 1:(m/2)
    cols_range = (i-1)*ncols_r + (1:ncols_r);
    M2(2*i-1, cols_range) = r(i,:);    
    M2(2*i,   cols_range) = r(i+1,:);    
end
```

There are some other constraints on `n` and `m` which you should take care of to make it work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

#### Manually generalising using `zeros`

Let's call the original matrix `R`

```
R = [r1
     r2
     r3]; % r1, r2 and r3 denote 1x4 rows
```

Then we could start to generalise the process by creating your output using `zeros` and individual row indexing.

```
c = size(R, 2); % Number of columns in R. In the original case this is 4.
M = [R(1,:), zeros(1,c);
     R(2,:), zeros(1,c);
     zeros(1,c); R(2,:);
     zeros(1,c); R(3,:);]
```

Better still, get the number of rows and use 2D `zeros` matrices and multiple row indexing.

```
[r, c] = size(R); % Rows and columns in R
halfr = ceil(r/2);  % Assuming odd number of rows in original matrix 
M = [R(1:halfr, :),   zeros(halfr, c);
     zeros(halfr, c), R(halfr:end, :)];
```

---

#### Using `kron` for tiling

We still need the sizes of R

```
[r, c] = size(R);
halfr = ceil(r/2);
```

Then we can create the tiling you want using `kron`

```
k = kron([1 0; 0 1], ones(halfr, c));
```

Repeat the middle row of `R` and repeat the whole thing side-by-side

```
R2 = R([1:halfr, halfr:end], [1:end, 1:end])
```

Use element-wise multiplication

```
M = k.*R2
```

Bulk of the work in one line:

```
[r, c] = size(R);
halfr = ceil(r/2);
M = kron([1 0; 0 1], ones(halfr, c)) .* R([1:halfr, halfr:end], [1:end, 1:end]);
```